# Tensorflow: How should I properly handle graphs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to set up a network using tf.contrib.learn functionalities:

```
#Imports, definition of directory paths..

def main(unused_argv):
    hparams = seg_hparams.create_hparams()

    input_fn_train = seg_inputs.create_input_fn(
            hparams = hparams,
            mode = tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
            input_dir = TRAIN_DATA)

    model_fn = seg_model.create_model_fn(
            hparams,
            model_impl = forward_backward_model)

    estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
            model_fn = model_fn,
            model_dir = MODEL_DIR)


    estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

For the input I am using a custom queue similar to the one described in the tutorial on https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-input-part2-extensions/.

When running the program, I encounter following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 54, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 49, in main
    estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 332, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 650, in _train_model
    train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 951, in _get_train_ops
    _, loss, train_op = self._call_model_fn(features, targets, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 934, in _call_model_fn
        ....
ValueError: Tensor("random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:0", shape=(6, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0) must be from the same graph as Tensor("seg_net/conv1/weights:0", shape=(3, 3, 1, 32), dtype=float32_ref).
```

Essentially I am wondering how to make sure to use the same graph across different functions.
I was thinking of something like using

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
```

inside input_fn_train and

```
with tf.get_default_graph():
```

inside model_fn.

However, I couldn't resolve the issue so far.

Comment: Easiest way to get rid of multiple-Graph confusion is to remove all places that create new graphs. `tf.reset_default_graph` and `tf.Graph()` will create new graphs. You can do `with g.as_default()` to make sure you use same graph when constructing things in other threads (default graph is thread local)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was able to resolve the issue by creating a graph in the main function: `graph = tf.Graph()`, passing it to the individual functions and using `with graph.as_default():` inside the functions.